# hex integer to integer in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, integer, hex

Similar questions already asked, but please can anyone explain to me why this code...

```
NSInteger hexInt = 0x80000505;
NSLog(@"%d, %#x", hexInt, hexInt);
```

prints out `-2147482363, 0x80000505` while 0x80000505 equals to 2147484933 and **not to -2147482363** ?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSInteger is defined as int (`typedef int NSInteger`) and 2147484933 overflows int maximal value (on 32 bit systems, where the range of int is  −2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647), because as you can see, the highest bit is set in 0x80000505, so 0x80000505 is a negative number.

Comment: So using NSLog(@"**%lld**, %#x", hexInt, hexInt); solves the problem. Thank you.